# Ubuntu 13.10 on Acer V5-472 with HD 4000

Tags: installation, intel-graphics, ubuntu-10.10

I have an Acer V5-472 with intel HD4000 graphics chipset and a built-in 1366*768 display.

I have installed ubuntu 13.10 amd64 in legacy boot mode with an external monitor.

Installation showed no problems, I can boot from HDD and log into my system.

The internal display doesn't work and I have to use an external monitor.

I have tried the following (found in other threads) to no avail:

1. Setting grub option "acpi_backlight=vendor" or "acpi_osi=Linux" or both.
2. Installing the intel HD drivers for Linux from their homepage.
3. Running in circles, screaming and shouting.

The internal display lights up (I can change the brightness with Fn-Left and Fn-Right) but that's all.

When I boot, I get a purple splash screen and from then only the external monitor works.

I read somewhere that this might be a problem with kernel 3.11? Has anybody ubuntu running on an Acer V5-472? Should I change ubuntu version or use 32-bit instead? In general, how can I get the internal display to work?

Edit: The settings->display dialogue shows the internal display correctly with supported resolution of 1366.

Comment: Have you tried a live cd of another release if you suspect the kernel?

Comment: I am now downloading 12.10.4 LTS.

Comment: @Ramhound Same behaviour with ubuntu LTS. I get loads and loads of "[drm:intel_dp_i2c_aux_ch] *ERROR* too many retries".